# Clojure : missing namespace errors when running "use" at the REPL

Tags: namespaces, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have a .clj file that starts like this :

```
(ns clojure_crawl.core)
(require '[clj-http.client :as client])
(use 'clojure.contrib.json)
```

Followed by several function definitions :

```
(defn f1 [] "" (+ 1 1))

(defn f2 [] "" (+ 2 2))
```

etc...

However, when I run the command "(use 'myfile.core :reload)"

Some of my functions , although visible at the REPL, cannot run do to "missing namespace" errors.

How do I add the dependencies so that the REPL can run any of the functions defined in my file ?

Answer (score 5):

If your code is in "clojure_crawl/core.clj", its namespace should be clojure-crawl.core (note the hyphen). See http://clojure.org/libs

Answer (score 3):

As Joost already said, you have to be careful with hyphens and underscores: wherever you use a hyphen in your namespace names, replace it with an underscore in the corresponding file/directory names (and vice versa).

Also, the use of the `require` and `use` functions in clj source files is discouraged. Instead, declare the libraries you need directly in the `ns` macro:

```
(ns clojure-crawl.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
  (:use clojure.contrib.json))
```

This also takes the burden of properly quoting the required namespaces from you.